# Adding Unique Slug in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a slug field in my school project, Here's what I tried in my model,

```
def pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

   slug = slugify(instance.title)
   exists = Data.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
   if exists:
      instance.slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, instance.id)
   else:
      instance.slug = slug



pre_save.connect(pre_save_receiver, sender=Data)
```

Everything is working fine but the problem is that it's adding ID in slug field behind even if it's Unique. 
How can I fix that?

Comment: what is output you are currently getting ?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Sir, suppose I added title as "new title" then instead of giving "new-title" in the slug. It's giving "new-title-(& here title's id)". Even when the title "new title" is Unique.

Comment: you should try some str.replace method , as it is giving "new-title-(& here title's id)" then you should format it like slugis="new-title-(& here title's id)".replace("-(& here title's id","")

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Sir, can you please explain it in detail? I couldn't understand how can I change code?

Comment: in which line you are getting slug ?

Comment: Sir, I'm slugifying the title & then checking it's existence. If it already exists then i'm doing `instance.slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, instance.id)`.

Comment: i think it should solve issue  instance.slug = "%s-%s" % (slug.replace("-(& here title's id",""), instance.id)

Comment: If an `instance.id` is being appended to your slug, it is because `Data.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()` is returning `True`. It's difficult to tell why that's happening without seeing the rest of your code. I'd recommend running `python manage.py shell`, importing an `instance`, and attempting to run through your code manually to figure out why `exists` is `True` in this case.

Comment: @Sam Sir, I tried using len() to count the length of slug & then using if else statement. But len() is counting length to be 1 even when slug doesn't exist. Why so?

Answer (score 1):

Model at least has the following:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug  = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
```

You need to create a file named utils in your app folder which contains the following code:

**utils.py**

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

def random_string_generator(size=10, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=None):
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    else:
        slug = slugify(instance.title)

    Klass = instance.__class__
    qs_exists = Klass.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
    if qs_exists:
        new_slug = "{slug}-{randstr}".format(
                    slug=slug,
                    randstr=random_string_generator(size=4)
                )
        return unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save

from .utils import unique_slug_generator

def pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
    instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_receiver, sender=YourModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get id of non-existing model. **pre_save** signal calls before model saves. Instead of **pre_save** use **post_save** signal